# How to use get_strong/get_weak with co_await

Tags: c++, c++-winrt, winrt-async

I was reading the following documentation -
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/weak-references#safely-accessing-the-this-pointer-in-a-class-member-coroutine

I understand that weak/strong ref is needed so that we do not dereference deleted object (this) in a coroutine. So, if there is a co_await statement in a coroutine and I am referencing a class member (function or data member) after that co_await, do I always have to have strong/weak ref? Or are there cases where we can skip it?

One example in the doc mentioned is around event source and event recipient lifetime such that when source triggers event, if recipient is guaranteed to be alive, we can skip capturing this by strong//weak ref.

Is there a such case in case of plain coroutine or do I always have to take a ref?

Comment: If you're sure that the current object stay alive (and also for eventual parameters received by reference), you do not need to maintain them alive. When the 1st co_await is reach, the caller will continue and all can happens. That may include a lot of things done after, and can include the end of the current object. Once again, if you're sure the object is here several seconds later, you do not have to lock it in memory.

Comment: The only time it's safe to *not* capture a strong reference from an event delegate implementation (and still access the class instance) is when you've registered for the event using a strong reference. Doing so, however, can create a reference cycle, introducing the risk of making it impossible to release resources associated with a class altogether. While possible to get all of this to work, it leads to code that's hard to maintain and hard to read. If you somehow manage to write this code, it's not unlikely for the code to be instantly too hard for you to understand. Best not to.

Comment: @IInspectable If you register an event handler with a weak reference, the C++/WinRT infrastructure will [upgrade it to a strong reference before calling your handler](https://github.com/microsoft/cppwinrt/blob/bf4459b25aeeb7093e8262fb3b29ca70b0ab2e60/strings/base_delegate.h#L184). If your event handler does not `co_await`, then you can rely on that strong reference for the lifetime of the event handler.

Comment: @RaymondChen You are right. I completely forgot about the `weak_ref<>` template specialization that auto-upgrades to a strong reference. When the `weak_ref` can be resolved to a strong reference, it is bound to a variable with automatic lifetime that outlives the event handler. I would have instinctively expected that to be sufficient to span any suspension points if the event handler is a coroutine, but now I realize that the strong reference isn't part of the delegate's local state. That feels like a nasty trap. Can/should this be changed?

Comment: @IInspectable How do you propose fixing this? The strong reference is kept across the call to the handler. The fact that the handler queues asynchronous work and returns immediately is not knowable by the lambda.

Comment: @RaymondChen I wasn't proposing a fix. I went as far as calling the implemented behavior surprising: There's automatic lifetime-extension, unless the client does something odd (like changing the return type from `void` to `fire_and_forget`). As for *"changing"* *"this"*, that could mean a number of things, e.g., improving the documentation, or purging the surprising adaptor, or adjusting the adaptor implementation to account for coroutines. The latter would be ideal, but I don't know how to identify a coroutine at compile time. Can this be done?

Comment: The object remains alive for the duration of the function call, just like any other function. If you `co_await`, then you are returning from the function call and scheduling further work later, in which case you are responsible for extending the lifetime to the future work. It just follows the normal rules for function calls. (You can't tell whether a function is a coroutine from outside the coroutine. Furthermore, even if you could, `fire_and_forget` cannot be awaited, so you don't know when the coroutine is done.)

Comment: @RaymondChen That phrasing paints a more consistent image. Everything follows normal rules, and there aren't any special cases here. Thanks for your patience.